# Auto-detect dates when dynamically creating ElasticSearch indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

I've just started using the rest api to put documents into ElasticSearch having always used Logstash to do this in the past.

How do I get ES to recognise dates when I pass it a string or integer?
I've tried both 13 digit "millis since epoc" (as string and integer) format and yyyyMMddTHHmmss.SSSZ (ISO 8601) format. Neither seem to get parsed.

Looking at documents that Logstash has successfully indexed, it seems to use the "millis since epoc" method, and I know those indexes are dynamically created. Submitting mappings for each index is not an option for me.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date detection is covered in detail in the [dynamic field mapping section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection) of the documentation.

By default, either `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z` or `yyyy/MM/dd Z` can be used, but you can customize that further on a per-index basis if you want.

Comment: Cheers, that's done it .NET: DateTime.ToString("O") is picked up correctly.